# Right sidebars overlapping one another

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I'm trying to create responsive right column. The problems is that when I create a new div for the right column it over laps the previous right sidebar. How can I fix this?

Here's the [LINK](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aCmGe)

My CSS:

```
.columnsContainer, footer, header { position: relative; margin: .5em; }

.leftColumn, .rightColumn, footer, header {  border: 1px solid  #ccc; padding: 1.25em; }

.leftColumn { margin-bottom: .5em; }

/* MEDIA QUERIES */
@media screen and (min-width: 47.5em ) {
  .leftColumn { margin-right: 19.5em; }

    .rightColumn { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; width: 18.75em; }   
}
```

Thank You

Comment: do you mean overlapping of Right Column and its below div?

Comment: have you tried creating margin-bottom: 'some desired value' for your .rightColumn

Comment: @RahulSambari Yes I meant that.

Comment: @RahulSambari I did try that but its still overlapping

Comment: did you try adding margin-top to the new div elements added to rightColumn ?

Comment: if you can give a jsfiddle of problematic scenario..it would be easy to handle.

Comment: I did provide the codepen link..

Comment: What is expected to happen if the right column is higher than the left column? does it scroll, or does it push the footer down leaving the left area blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoul think of your layout. The problem comes up with your styling. Especialy the `position: absolut` causes problems.

**SIMPLE BASIC TAMPLATE**

You should create a column left, a column right and a footer. Then place the content in each column.

[image]

A basic layout for this could be:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="col-left">
        Column left 
        <div class="content-left">
            content left content
        </div>
        <div class="content-left">
            content left content
        </div>
        <div class="content-left">
            content left content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        Column right
        <div class="content-right">
            content right content
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            content right content
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            content right content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        footer
        <div class="content-footer">
            footer conten
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS could look like:

```
.wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
.col-left{
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.col-right{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: ActiveCaption;
}
.footer{
    clear: both;
    background-color: bisque;
    height: 100px;
}
.content-left{
    height: 100px;
}

.content-left, .content-right, .content-footer{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

This is just a sample of a basic responsive layout. You can easely adjust it for your needs.

[SEE SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/qvwzdvau/)

UPDATE:

You can use [media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) to make it finally responsive.

Query

```
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .col-left, .col-right{
        width: 100%;  
        float: none;
     }
}
```

Updated [SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/qvwzdvau/1/)

```css
    .wrapper{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-left{
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    .col-right{
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
        background-color: ActiveCaption;
    }
    .footer{
        clear: both;
        background-color: bisque;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .content-left{
        height: 100px;
    }

    .content-left, .content-right, .content-footer{
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 700px){
        .col-left, .col-right{
            width: 100%;  
            float: none;
         }
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="col-left">
            Column left 
            <div class="content-left">
                content left content
            </div>
            <div class="content-left">
                content left content
            </div>
            <div class="content-left">
                content left content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-right">
            Column right
            <div class="content-right">
                content right content
            </div>
            <div class="content-right">
                content right content
            </div>
            <div class="content-right">
                content right content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            footer
            <div class="content-footer">
                footer conten
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How can I make this responsive? I mean the right content doesnt come below the left content on resizing..

Comment: The same way you did it in your sample! Use media queries!

Comment: I made a update for you @nabeela If that helps dont forget to upvote the answer